How to check if image is already in Coil managed memory?
As the title says is there any way to know if an image is already in the cache?
I have a screen containing a list of image, clicking on an item will navigate to the detail screen for that item, the navigation is delayed until the item is successfully loaded.

I want when clicking on the loaded image, the navigation should happen immediately (the image is already in the cache). But I don't know how to check if the image is already in the cache.
Here are the codes:
@Composable
fun NavigateMap(navController: NavHostController = rememberNavController(),
            viewModel: BookViewModel = viewModel(factory = BookViewModel.Factory)) {
val context= LocalContext.current
val imageLoader = ImageLoader.Builder(context)
        .respectCacheHeaders(false)
        .build()

val uiState by viewModel.uiState.collectAsState()
NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = BookScreenMap.Start.name) {
    composable(route = BookScreenMap.Start.name) {
        BookHome(onBookClick = { id ->
            viewModel.getPhotoById(id,imageLoader,context)
        })
    }
    composable(route = BookScreenMap.Detail.name) {
        DetailsScreen(
            uiState.thumbnail, title = uiState.title,
            authors = uiState.authors,
            description = uiState.description)
    }
}

val shouldNavigate=viewModel.shouldNavigate
LaunchedEffect(shouldNavigate) {
    if(shouldNavigate){
        navController.navigate(BookScreenMap.Detail.name)
        viewModel.shouldNavigate = false
    }
}
}

ViewMode Code:
class BookViewModel(private val bookRepository: BookRepository) : ViewModel() {
      var shouldNavigate by mutableStateOf(false)
      var fetchUiState:FetchUiState by mutableStateOf(FetchUiState.Loading)
         private set
      var fetchPhotoBook:FetchPhotoBook by mutableStateOf(FetchPhotoBook.Normal)
         private set
      private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(BookUiState("", "","", "Chưa rõ",""))
      val uiState = _uiState.asStateFlow()

      init {
         getListBook("live",10)
      }



      fun getPhotoById(id: String, imageLoader: ImageLoader,
                 context: Context) {
         viewModelScope.launch {
         val infoBook = safeApiCall {
            bookRepository.getBookById(id).volumeInfo
      }
        infoBook?.let {
            val imageUrl = it.imageLinks?.medium.toString().replace("http:", "https:")
            updateBookUiState(
                thumbnail =imageUrl,
                title = it.title,
                authors = it.authors?.joinToString(", ") ?: "Unknown",
                description =HtmlCompat.fromHtml(it.description.orEmpty(), HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY).toString()
            )
            val cachedImage // how to check image in cache

            if (cachedImage ) {
                shouldNavigate=true

            } else {

                val request = ImageRequest.Builder(context)
                    .data(imageUrl)

                    .diskCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED)
                    .memoryCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED)
                    .networkCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED)
                    .diskCacheKey(imageUrl)
                    .memoryCacheKey(imageUrl)
                    .decoderFactory { _, _, _ ->
                        Decoder { DecodeResult(ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK), false) }
                    }
                    .listener(
                        onStart={ _ ->
                            fetchPhotoBook=FetchPhotoBook.Loading
                            Log.d("Request Start","Start")
                        }
                        ,
                        onSuccess = { _, _ ->
             
                            shouldNavigate=true
                        }
                        

                    )
                    .build()
                imageLoader.enqueue(request)
            }


        } ?: run {
            Log.d("BOOK_INFO", "No data found")
        }
    }
}


private suspend fun <T> safeApiCall(apiCall: suspend () -> T): T? {
    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        try {
            apiCall()
        } catch (e: HttpException) {
            Log.e("ApiCall", "HTTP exception occurred", e)
            null
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Log.e("ApiCall", "Network or IO exception occurred", e)
            null
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("ApiCall", "Unexpected exception occurred", e)
            null
        }
    }
}

...........

}

I would consider not to wait with the navigation until the image is loaded.

When there is slow internet connection, the user will think that the app froze because nothing is happening after their click
The user has no chance to see what is going on in the background
The user has no chance to cancel the ongoing network request

Instead, I would delegate the responsability for loading the thumbnail image to the DetailScreen. You can display a loading animation in Coil using a SubComposeAsyncImage:
SubcomposeAsyncImage(
    model = "https://example.com/image.jpg",
    loading = {
        CircularProgressIndicator()
    },
    contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.description)
)

Also, as far as I can tell, your BookHome Composable already shows all thumbnails in a Grid. Are these coming from the same URL as the DetailScreen thumbnails? If yes, you can be sure that the images are already in cache.

The images from the two screens do not have the same URL, on the first screen I only fetch the low quality images and their IDs, when selected for detail I fetch the high quality images as well as other information from the id. I noticed that when loading high quality images in bulk using coil it is very slow. I expected the effect like in https://play.google.com/store/books?pli=1

In that case you could immediately navigate to the details screen and display the thumbnail (that is guaranteed to be already cached) and start loading the hi-res image in the backrgound. When loaded switch out the thumbnail with the hi-res image.

Your opinion is probably the same as in the coil document section "Using Cache Key as Placeholder", I did it and achieved the expectation, of course there is a trade-off when the thumbnail is enlarged. I think in Google Play Book, they just load the thumbnail then display at the appropriate size for the clearest image and load the high quality image in the background, when I click on the thumbnail in the detail screen to see the larger image (high quality image), then the placeholder image is displayed for 1-4s. @Leviathan
